# How to view pdf file in browser using PHP Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
function view_file() {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $file = realpath('./uploads/'.$id);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        @readfile($file);
    }
```

> this is my controller there is no error but it automatically download the pdf file and it didn't view in web browser

Answer (score 0):

set `Content-disposition` to inline in the header:

```
header("Content-disposition: inline;filename=".$id);
```

Comment: it automatically download maybe because I have a downloader?.

Comment: Maybe can you disable the downloader? or change setting of it

Comment: Even in, If you use chrome browser it also has a setting: setting > Site Settings > PDF Documents.